# What does this expression means in the GroupBy method?

Tags: c#, linq

```
bool test = anyCollection.GroupBy(x => "AnyKeyString").Any(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

It'll always return true by this Lambda, where I think it means "give the placeholder x as true(because the string itself is always true??), and group by any things in the collection which is true"

My question is why I put a string in the GroupBy is always return true?

I'm not pretty sure, I was inspired when I find the duplicate values in a collection, here is the example:

```
    public class Alphabet
    {
      public int ID { get; set; }
      public string Initial { get; set; }
    }

        List<Alphabet> testList = new List<Alphabet>()
        {
            new Alphabet() { ID = 1, Initial = "A"},
            new Alphabet() { ID = 2, Initial = "B"},
            new Alphabet() { ID = 3, Initial = "C"},
            new Alphabet() { ID = 4, Initial = "D"},
        };

        List<Alphabet> testList2 = new List<Alphabet>()
        {
            new Alphabet() { ID = 1, Initial = "A"},
            new Alphabet() { ID = 2, Initial = "A"},
            new Alphabet() { ID = 3, Initial = "C"},
            new Alphabet() { ID = 4, Initial = "C"},
        };

        bool test1 = testList.GroupBy(x => x.Initial).Any(g => g.Count() > 1);
        // false
        bool test2 = testList2.GroupBy(x => x.Initial).Any(g => g.Count() > 1);
        // true
        bool test3 = testList2.GroupBy(x => "Initial").Any(g => g.Count() > 1);
        // true
```

A bit off topic, and how could I group by a generic type list?

```
    List<string> testList = new List<string>(){
        "A",
        "B",
        "C",
        "D"
    };

    List<string> testList2 = new List<string>(){
        "A",
        "A",
        "C",
        "D"
    };

    var k = testList.GroupBy(x => ????).Any(g => g.Count() > 1);
    var c = testList2.GroupBy(x => "A").Any(g => g.Count() > 1);
    // always true
```

Comment: `x => "anystring"` isn't a predicate - it's not true or false, it's selecting the key for the grouping. `testList2.GroupBy(x => "anystring").Any(g => g.Count() > 1)` is equivalent to `testList2.Count() > 1`

Comment: so what is it pointing? at least there is no such key exist so why it is returning true??

Comment: Oh, is that your question? `.GroupBy()` isn't `.Where()`. It isn't a filter.

Comment: @john nope, it is my question, that's looking for duplicate records, and if you take the .Any() off it still means the same :)

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I said. `testList2.GroupBy(x => "anystring").Any(g => g.Count() > 1)` will create one group with all items (so it's pointless), and then check if that group has more than one item.

Comment: ah, sorry it was me misleading the question, I understand the groupBy is taking the key selector, and actually I was tried to see if I can pointed to a dynamic key(sth lik Type.GetProperty("anyString")), in fact I doesn't mean group by a particular string, sry abt that

Comment: Then what exactly is your question? You can't just change your question completely after somebody has answered it. You asked why `.GroupBy("anystring")` "returned true", which I've answered and given a full explanation off. Now you've changed your question to ask a very different thing.

Comment: @john I didn't change my question, I wonder why the expression still can be grouped when the key is pointing to nth. but I was saying sorry for the question might make you think I was doing filter

Comment: Because you're selecting a static value as the key, as I've answered? Your question now seems to be asking how to dynamically supply the source property for the key, which is a different question.

Comment: I think the "static value" is right to the answer thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.GroupBy` isn't a filter - it isn't `.Where`. `.GroupBy` takes a *key selector*: `Func<TObject, TKey>`

So if you have a function like this (equivalent to `x => x.Initial`):

```
public string GetGroupKeyForObject(Alphabet alpha)
{
    return alpha.Initial;
}
```

<sub>Which could be passed as: `.GroupBy(GetGroupKeyForObject)`</sub>

Then it will group by the initial. But if you have a function like this (equivalent to `x => "anystring"`):

```
public string GetGroupKeyForObject(Alphabet alpha)
{
    return "anystring";
}
```

then *all items* will be determined to have the key "anystring" for the purposes of grouping.

If you only want to select items whose initial is "anystring" you should do this:

```
bool result = testList.Where(a => a.Initial == "anystring").Count() > 1;
```

or a slightly more efficient (but less readable way):

```
bool result = testList.Where(a => a.Initial == "anystring").Skip(1).Any();
```

Imagine you have this test set:

Alphabets (showing only Initial for brevity, but the same object as yours): `["A", "A","B", "B", "B", "B","C","D","E","F"]`

And you group it by Initial, you'll get 6 groups:

Key: Group items

A: `["A", "A"]`

B: `["B", "B", "B", "B"]`

C: `["C"]`

D: `["D"]`

E: `["E"]`

F: `["F"]`

But if you group it by "anystring", you'll get 1 group:

Key: Group items

anystring: `["A", "A","B", "B", "B", "B","C","D","E","F"]`

So performing `.Any(x => x.Count() > 1)` on the first example, will return `true` because A and B had a count above 1.
Performing the same on the second example is the same as calling `.Count() > 1` on the original collection, because you're grouping the entire selection by a static value, so you only get one group.